# React native iOS linking issue - securerandom - how do I check if linked?

Tags: react-native, linker

I'm new to react-native. Overall going well, however I've run into an issue where I need to use a native library for iOS. In this case I need to generate random bytes (I decided to use: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-securerandom).

Here's the error I get:

```
react-native-securerandom is not properly linked
at node_modules/react-native-securerandom/index.js:8:35 in generateSecureRandom
```

I've already run (as specified here: https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking-libraries-ios)

```
npx react-native link
```

How do I check what libraries are linked? What else do I need to do?

I'm using windows (VScode) / WSL2 for development, and I test on iOS device using `expo start` and scanning QR code which launches on the phone.

Comment: Are you using an Expo managed or bare workflow? https://docs.expo.dev/introduction/managed-vs-bare/

Comment: @jnpdx, I'm using managed workflow; looking at the table in the link looks like that doesn't support native dependencies :( Do you recommend I switch to Bare? Is it easy to switch, how much effort in refactoring?

Comment: If you want to use native, yes, you'll have to switch. There really isn't any refactoring. The biggest downside is you'll actually have to wait for compile times when rebuilding the project (JS changes alone will still reload with Hot Reload)

Comment: Ok thanks, I made bare setup, and copied all my files over. Looks like I need a mac to build or via cloud. Will try this later. Thanks, for the help!

Comment: Yes, you'd need a Mac or the cloud to build for iOS. FYI for future projects, instead of making a new bare setup and copying files, you can use Expo's `eject` command to automate the process for you.